# Horizontal recycleView inside Vertical RecycleView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to make playstore like layout i.e Horizontal recycleView inside Vertical RecycleView, I have a parent list like:
`[{"pid":1,"name":XYX},{"pid":2,"name":ABC}]`

and child list as shown below when I pass pid=1

`[{"cid":1,"name":WWW,"pid":1},{"cid":2,"name":RRR,"pid":1}]`

and when I pass pid=2

`[{"cid":1,"name":DDD,"pid":2},{"cid":2,"name":VVV,"pid":2}]`

I want to make it dynamic because parent and child list size can change.
***So where should I make the api call for Child list***

Any Suggestion would be helpful

Comment: can you share code? what you have done yet?

Comment: This link may help : http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Answer (score 0):

`onBindViewHolder` of the parent adapter